# Payload of API call in flutter bloc state

Tags: flutter, mvvm, bloc, clean-architecture, flutter-bloc

I use flutter clean architecture MVVM and BLOC state management.

I keep payload models in folder called as **entities** in Model View layer

Example of payload looks like:

```
@unfreezed
class AddTaskPayload with _$AddTaskPayload {
  factory AddTaskPayload({
    String? title,
    String? description,
    DateTime? date,
    TimeOfDay? startingTime,
    TimeOfDay? endingTime,
    TaskPriority? priority,
  }) = _AddTaskPayload;
}
```

My state in View layer looks like:

```
class AddTaskState extends Equatable {
  final ErrorModel? errorModel;
  final AddTaskEntity addTaskPayload;

  const AddTaskState({
    this.errorModel,
    required this.addTaskPayload,
  });

  AddTaskState copyWith({
    ErrorModel? errorModel,
    AddTaskPayload? addTaskPayload,
  }) {
    return AddTaskState(
      errorModel: errorModel,
      addTaskPayload: addTaskPayload ?? this.addTaskPayload,
    );
  }

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [
        errorModel,
        addTaskPayload,
      ];
}
```

and I have some questions:

1. Is it appropriate that I use in case of state management package Equatable and in case of rest models in app Freezed? Does it make sens to use Freezed in case of bloc state?
2. I wanted to avoid duplication of code and thats why I added final AddTaskEntity addTaskPayload in state class instead of 6 fields from AddTaskPayload, is it ok? I have some doubts because changing of specific field in payload will demand double call copyWith like:

   `emit(state.copyWith(addTaskPayload: state.addTaskPayload.copyWith(date: event.date)));`

Is it good practice or better to duplicate code and add in state all fields from payload class? How to do it in most efficient and correct way ? Because I suppose that douple copyWith will causes some performance issues when e.g. 3 payloads will be in state ?

3. Is Bloc example of MVC design pattern? We have View as a UI, we have model as a state class which keep current state and we have controller as a bloc which can modify state. Or its a bad way of thinking?